# The message client did not start

Tags: java, android, android-activity, parse-platform, sinch

I am using Sinch and Parse for my instant messaging system integrated in our application. For some reason, I am receiving the following error when the messaging activity is displayed: The message client did not start". Furthermore, the message does not seem to go through in Sinch and not reflected visually in the application.

Below is the activity code (when the user clicks on the "quick chat" button, it takes them to the messaging activity page.

```
public class matchOptionActivity extends Activity{

     protected TextView mUserRetrieved;
        private String currentUserId;

        protected TextView mUserActivityNameRetrieved;
        protected TextView mUserNameRetrieved;
        protected TextView mUserAgeRetrieved;
        protected TextView mUserHeadlineRetrieved;
        String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender");
        String activityName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("ActivityName");
        Number maxDistance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber(
                "Maximum_Distance");
        String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString(
                "Looking_Gender");
        Number minimumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Minimum_Age");
        Number maximumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Age");
        Number userage = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Age");




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.matchoption);

        final Button idrinks = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnQuickChat);
        idrinks.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openConversation();
            }

            private void openConversation() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
                    query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                            .getObjectId());
                    // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
                    query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
                    // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
                    query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
                    query.setLimit(1);
                    query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
                    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                        public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("Name", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Error finding that user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        }
                    });


            }
        });
    }
```

Below is the activity code for the messaging activity

```
public class MessagingActivity extends Activity implements ServiceConnection, MessageClientListener {

    private String recipientId;
    private Button sendButton;
    private EditText messageBodyField;
    private String messageBody;
    private MessageService.MessageServiceInterface messageService;
    private MessageAdapter messageAdapter;
    private ListView messagesList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.messaging);

        doBind();


        messagesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMessages);
        messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this);
        messagesList.setAdapter(messageAdapter);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        recipientId = intent.getStringExtra("Name");

        messageBodyField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageBodyField);
        sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendMessage();
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendMessage() {
        messageBodyField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageBodyField);
        messageBody = messageBodyField.getText().toString();
        if (messageBody.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        //Here is where you will actually send the message throught Sinch
        messageService.sendMessage(recipientId, messageBody);
        messageBodyField.setText("");
    }

    private void doBind() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MessageService.class);
        bindService(serviceIntent, this, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unbindService(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
        //Define the messaging service and add a listener
        messageService = (MessageService.MessageServiceInterface) iBinder;
        messageService.addMessageClientListener(this);
        if (!messageService.isSinchClientStarted()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "The message client did not start."
                ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        messageService = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageDelivered(MessageClient client, MessageDeliveryInfo deliveryInfo) {
        //Intentionally  left blank
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageFailed(MessageClient client, Message message,
                                MessageFailureInfo failureInfo) {
        //Notify the user if message fails to send
        Toast.makeText(this, "Message failed to send.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onIncomingMessage(MessageClient client, Message message) {
        messageAdapter.addMessage(message, MessageAdapter.DIRECTION_INCOMING);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageSent(MessageClient client, Message message, String recipientId) {
        messageAdapter.addMessage(message, MessageAdapter.DIRECTION_OUTGOING);
    }

    @Override
    public void onShouldSendPushData(MessageClient client, Message message, List<PushPair> pushPairs) {
        //Intentionally left blank
    }
}
```

I have verified that the APP_KEY, the APP_SECRET and ENVIRONMENT matches what was recorded on Sinch.
I have tried this both on the emulator, and on a physical device.

Thanks in advance

Code service

```
public class MessageService extends Service implements SinchClientListener {

    private static final String APP_KEY = "XXXXX";
    private static final String APP_SECRET = "YYYYY";
    private static final String ENVIRONMENT = "sandbox.sinch.com";
    private final MessageServiceInterface serviceInterface = new MessageServiceInterface();
    private SinchClient sinchClient = null;
    private MessageClient messageClient = null;
    private String currentUserId;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId().toString();

        if (currentUserId != null && !isSinchClientStarted()) {
            startSinchClient(currentUserId);
        }

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public void startSinchClient(String username) {
        sinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(this).userId(username).applicationKey(APP_KEY)
                .applicationSecret(APP_SECRET).environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT).build();

        sinchClient.addSinchClientListener(this);

        sinchClient.setSupportMessaging(true);
        sinchClient.setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground(true);

        sinchClient.checkManifest();
        sinchClient.start();
    }

    private boolean isSinchClientStarted() {
        return sinchClient != null && sinchClient.isStarted();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClientFailed(SinchClient client, SinchError error) {
        sinchClient = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClientStarted(SinchClient client) {
        client.startListeningOnActiveConnection();
        messageClient = client.getMessageClient();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClientStopped(SinchClient client) {
        sinchClient = null;
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (isSinchClientStarted()) {
            sinchClient.stop();
            sinchClient.removeSinchClientListener(this);
        }
        sinchClient = null;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return serviceInterface;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogMessage(int level, String area, String message) {
        //Intentionally left blank
    }

    @Override
    public void onRegistrationCredentialsRequired(SinchClient client, ClientRegistration clientRegistration) {
        //Intentionally left blank
    }

    public void sendMessage(String recipientUserId, String textBody) {
        if (messageClient != null) {
            WritableMessage message = new WritableMessage(recipientUserId, textBody);
            messageClient.send(message);
        }
    }

    public void addMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
        if (messageClient != null) {
            messageClient.addMessageClientListener(listener);
        }
    }

    public void removeMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
        if (messageClient != null) {
            messageClient.removeMessageClientListener(listener);
        }
    }

    public class MessageServiceInterface extends Binder {

        public void sendMessage(String recipientUserId, String textBody) {
            MessageService.this.sendMessage(recipientUserId, textBody);
        }

        public void addMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
            MessageService.this.addMessageClientListener(listener);
        }

        public void removeMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
            MessageService.this.removeMessageClientListener(listener);
        }

        public boolean isSinchClientStarted() {
            return MessageService.this.isSinchClientStarted();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Without seeing the code for the service, you are checking if `SinchClient` is started as soon as your service starts (`onServiceConnected`). Chances are that the `SinchClient` does not have time to start properly in the short time span between the service is launched and your activity connects to the service.

I would suggest that you add an interface to the service, which exposes something like `onSinchClientStarted` that is called when the `SinchClient` in your service has actually started (and you got the `onClientStarted` callback in the service).

Comment: thank you for response and the clarification. To give you a better understanding I have added the code service under the code service section of my initial post.